# How to get notified when the other end of a socketpair is closed?

Tags: ipc, unix-sockets

I have a parent process (client) talking with a child process (server) over Unix Domain sockets (aka IPC Sockets).

The sockets are created using `socketpair()` and are of type datagram.

I use `posix_spawn()` to start the child process, and `close()` the end of the socket pair that I don't need in the parent and child.

On the child I use `poll()` and `recv()`.

This all works great.

Now, I want the child (server) to be notified when the client closes their end of the socket or when the client terminates.

I was expecting to get a `POLLHUP` or `POLLERR` event on `close()`, but I don’t get anything.

When using `lsof -U` to list the Unix Domain sockets opened by my 2 process I see that the other end of the socket is `none` after the client is killed.

This is on macOS if this matters.

What am I missing? How does one get notified when a client close a Unix Domain socket?

Answer (score 1):

I've put together a sample application based on your description, with some small differences.  First, I use `SOCK_STREAM` instead of `SOCK_DGRAM`.  This change is what gives me the behavior that you're looking for -- `POLLHUP` means that the socket is no longer connected; `SOCK_DGRAM` isn't a connection-oriented socket.  Is there a reason that you need to use `SOCK_DGRAM`?

A second small difference between this example and what you describe is that I use `fork()` instead of `posix_spawn()`.  That shouldn't affect the behavior in which you're interested; it was just easier for me to write the self-contained example with `fork()`.

```c
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int sockets[2] = {};

    if (socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sockets) < 0) {
        perror("socketpair");
        return 1;
    }

    const pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        return 2;
    }

    if (pid > 0) {
        /* parent */
        close(sockets[0]);
        sockets[0] = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            write(sockets[1], "hello", sizeof("hello"));
            sleep(2);
        }

        /* sockets[1] will get closed on parent termination */
        return 0;
    }

    /* child */
    close(sockets[1]);
    sockets[1] = 0;

    struct pollfd fds = {
        .fd = sockets[0],
        .events = POLLIN | POLLHUP,
    };

    while (poll(&fds, 1, 10 * 1000) > 0) {
        if (fds.revents & POLLHUP) {
            printf("--- Received hangup\n");
            break;
        }
        if (fds.revents & POLLERR) {
            printf("!!! Received error\n");
            break;
        }
        if (fds.revents & POLLIN) {
            char buffer[32] = {};

            if (recv(sockets[0], buffer, sizeof buffer, 0) < 0) {
                perror("recv");
                return 3;
            }

            printf("--> Received message '%s'\n", buffer);
        }
    }

    /* sockets[0] will get closed on child termination */
    return 0;
}
```

In this program, the parent writes messages to the child; the child receives those messages and processes them (here, just prints them to standard output).  The parent sends 3 messages, then terminates.

When I run this program, I see the behavior that I think you're looking for:

```
$ ./a.out
--> Received message 'hello'
--> Received message 'hello'
--> Received message 'hello'
--- Received hangup
```

If you must use `SOCK_DGRAM` then the call to `poll()` will eventually timeout (in my example I have a 10-second timeout).  You could shut down the client process on that event.

Comment: SOCK_DGRAM is required because it gives me message framing for free. A stream doesn't. But the sample is good. In my case, (on macOS with DGRAM) I never get the POLLHUP, but I do get a POLLIN event on close, and modulo a bug where I wasn't checking the return value of recv properly, this works.

Comment: Ah, and the other thing is that it works if the client close() it's socket, but not if the client is killed or exit before calling close().

Comment: Your rationale for using `SOCK_DGRAM` makes sense.  I see similar behavior with my example; I don't think `POLLHUP` is expected with `SOCK_DGRAM` as there is no "connection" to the sender.

Comment: There shouldn't be a fundamental difference between `close()` and application termination.  When the application is terminated, its file descriptors are closed implicitly.

Comment: Well, UDP socket can be "connected" in some sense. That is you can call connect(2) on them. And the man page for socketpair explicitly mentioned "connected sockets". But I guess it doesn't mean exactly the same things.

Comment: It also looks like having a timeout and retrying poll() is key. It looks like poll is checking the connection status of the socket when it is called, and will return an POLLIN event right away if the socket was already disconnected before the call to poll, but will not return an event if it is disconnected while waiting. This may be platform specific (macOS in my case)

Comment: @Droopycom To be clear, there is no "connection" with a `SOCK_DGRAM` -- that's why you don't get a `POLLHUP` when the far end closes the file descriptor.  With `SOCK_DGRAM` the only option I see is to use the `poll()` timeout.  If you can't predict when the sender will send, you might also want some sort of periodic heartbeat to let the receiver know the sender is still around.